# What are the rules for _ underscore variables in C++26, and what's a name-independent declaration?

Tags: c++, identifier, local-variables, c++26

When I compile the following code, I get a warning (https://godbolt.org/z/Tx7v6jWf1):

```cpp
void foo() {
    int _;
    // warning: name-independent declarations only available with
    //           '-std=c++2c' or '-std=gnu++2c' [-Wc++26-extensions]
    int _;
}
```

What exactly has changed about `_` variables in C++26, and what's a *name-indepent declaration*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[P2169: A nice placeholder with no name](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2169r4.pdf) has been accepted into C++26, which makes `_` special in the following contexts:

- local variables (e.g. `int _`)
- local structured bindings (e.g. `auto [x, _]`)
- [init-capture](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#nt:init-capture)s (e.g. `[_ = 0] {}`)
- non-static data members of other than an anonymous union (e.g. `struct S { int _; }`)

In such contexts, `_` makes the declaration [name-independent](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#def:declaration,name-independent).

### `_` suppresses warnings

The standard says:

> *Recommended practice*: Implementations should not emit a warning that a [name-independent](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#def:declaration,name-independent) declaration is used or unused.

This is very similar to the recommendation for `[[maybe_unused]]` in [[dcl.attr.unused] p4](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.unused#4).
Normally, you would get a warning for unused variables (`-Wunused` in GCC), but `_` and `[[maybe_unused]]` suppress this.

Historically, developers have used `_` as a "placeholder" for unused things, so this is just standardizing existing practice.

### `_` can be declared multiple times

Furthermore, [name-independent](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#def:declaration,name-independent) declarations cannot [potentially conflict](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#def:potentially_conflict).
In short, you can declare `_` multiple times. However, name lookup cannot be ambiguous.

```cpp
void g() {
  int _;
  _ = 0;   // OK, and warning is not recommended
  int _;   // OK, name-independent declaration does not potentially conflict with the first _
  _ = 0;   // error: two non-function declarations in the lookup set
}
```

This code is taken from [[basic.scope.scope] example 3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.scope#example-3).

Note that `_` also has some special interactions with `using` declarations. See [[namespace.udecl] p10](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#10) for more details.

### Two `_` are not the same entity from the linker's perspective

Even with external linkage, two `_` are not considered the same entity:

```cpp
// a.cpp
int _ = 0;
```

```
// b.cpp
int _ = 0;
```

When linked, this program is OK.
For any name other than `_`, this would give you a "multiple definitions" linker error.
See also [[basic.link] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#8).

### Compiler Support

Only GCC 14 and Clang 18 support this feature at the time of writing.
See [C++26 compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/26) for more.

If you need to test for support, test for [`__cpp_placeholder_variables`](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:cpp.predefined.ft):

```cpp
#if __cpp_placeholder_variables >= 202306L
```

Comment: And it is again the committee that had ignored the wish of the larger community and went with cryptic syntax and unintuitive behaviour. using `std::ignore` would have been so much better and be more consistent. 

But now they want to add this mess. `static` changes how `_` is interpreted completely, you are allowed to read and write to that variable, you are allowed to have multiple otherwise conflicting declarations but only if not reading/asigning values!?! That is the opposite of what the proposal was supposed to solve. This will be the source of so many problems again.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf [P26968: Make `std::ignore` a first-class object](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2968r2.html) is likely going to be accepted into C++26 as well.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf In no way is this "cryptic syntax and unintuitive behavior" and in no way would using `std::ignore` to solve this problem be in any way "much better" or "more consistent." `ignore = lock_guard{mtx}` would immediately drop the lock, which is exactly not what you want.

Comment: @Barry In what way is it NOT cryptic when variables with a specific NAME compile, link and behave completely different from all other variables? 
And your example you explicitly do NOT want to ignore the variable so naming it `_` before was fine so again the change will not help in any way shape or form

Comment: On the other hand this proposal would allow things like declaring multiple variables with the same identifier and getting no warnings what so ever till the program is ill-defined just cause you wanted to make sure that the value you ignored really is unimportant.

With that proposal 
`std::lock_guard _{mtx}`; ... <insert some code> auto [x,_] = f();`
would compile but 
`std::lock_guard _{mtx}`; ... <insert some code> auto [x,_] = f(); .... asser( _ == nullptr);` would give you cryptic errors. 
Now tell me - what exactly do you propose becomes better?

Comment: @ABaumstumpf The error is [not at all cryptic](https://godbolt.org/z/Pbhsj9875) - it is very clear why it is ambiguous and the error here points you to all the variables.